A book reference for the coefficients of the Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind
I am looking for a book reference for the following equation, presenting the coefficients of the Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind:
$$U_n(x)= \sum\limits_{j=0}^{n/2} (-1)^j \binom{n-j}{j}(2x)^{n-2j}$$
Thank you very much, David.
